# How to create hashlib for the files and put into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hashlib

I have 4 files inside a folder `hash.py  size_1.py  size_2.py  size.py`. size_1.py , size_2.py is of same size.

I am creating hashlib for the files

```
import hashlib, os, sys
result = {}
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(".", topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        #print(os.path.join(root, name))
        FileName = (os.path.join(root, name))

        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        with open(str(FileName), 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
        file_hash = (afile,hasher.hexdigest())
        #print (file_hash)
        result[file_hash[1]] = file_hash[0]
        #if file_hash[1] in result:
        #    result[file_hash[1]].append(file_hash[0])
        #else:
        #    result[file_hash[1]] = file_hash[0]

print (result)
```

My Output

```
{'e12d780eba6e03a7c1cafa394ef9f31f': <_io.BufferedReader name='./size.py'>, '49eb7137273ec333727ea0f5279fe040': <_io.BufferedReader name='./size_1.py'>, '35e93b380f084d5187976beae746492e': <_io.BufferedReader name='./hash.py'>}
```

My Desired Out

```
{'e12d780eba6e03a7c1cafa394ef9f31f': ['./size.py']>, '49eb7137273ec333727ea0f5279fe040': ['./size_1.py','./size_1.py'], '35e93b380f084d5187976beae746492e': ['./hash.py']}
```

Here 2 uplift has to do

1. remove <_io.BufferedReader name=
2. put it in a dictionary format.

Comment: `afile` is the file object you create as a result of the `open` call, `FileName` is the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you create tuples where they don't required.

```
import hashlib, os, sys

result = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        fn = os.path.join(root, name)
        with open(fn, 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
            file_hash = hasher.hexdigest()
        if fn in result:
            result[fn].append(file_hash)
        else:
            result[fn] = [file_hash]
```

Comment: {'./size.py': ['e12d780eba6e03a7c1cafa394ef9f31f'], './size_2.py': ['49eb7137273ec333727ea0f5279fe040'],'./hash.py': ['bc2e95920d4bb451e2b80974773038a9'], './size_1.py': ['49eb7137273ec333727ea0f5279fe040']}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @olvin

```
import hashlib, os, sys

result = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        fn = os.path.join(root, name)
        with open(fn, 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
            file_hash = hasher.hexdigest()
        if file_hash in result:
            result[file_hash].append(fn)
        else:
            result[file_hash] = [fn]
print (result)
```